# xslt : test if any of the nodes at parent node level have a certain value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have simplified version of my xml here and I want to fill out the data in the parent nodes using the IMP value in the children if any, which should be true if any of the IMP values in the children are true. if no children exist then it should be false.

```
<info>
    <parent index='0'>
        <name>test1</name>
        <children>
        </children>
    </parent>
    <parent index='1'>
        <name>test2</name>
        <children>
            <VALUE index='0'>test3</VALUE>
            <VALUE index='1'>test4</VALUE>
        </children>
    </parent>
    <parent index='2'>
        <name>test3</name>
        <impvalue>true</impvalue>
    </parent>
    <parent index='3'>
        <name>test4</name>
        <impvalue>false</impvalue>
    </parent>
</info>
```

the output needed is

```
<info>
    <parent index='0'>
        <name>test1</name>
        <children>
        </children>
        <impvalue>false</impvalue>
    </parent>
    <parent index='1'>
        <name>test2</name>
        <children>
            <VALUE index='0'>test3</VALUE>
            <VALUE index='1'>test4</VALUE>
        </children>
        <impvalue>true</impvalue>
    </parent>
    <parent index='2'>
        <name>test3</name>
        <impvalue>true</impvalue>
    </parent>
    <parent index='3'>
        <name>test4</name>
        <impvalue>false</impvalue>
    </parent>
</info>
```

Comment: The input XML shared is not a well-formed XML. Please correct it by closing the `</VALUE>` tags and also provide correct tag names for `<IMP value>`. Tag names should not have a space in them. If `value` is an attribute of `<IMP>`, please provide it's value.

Comment: Fixed it, This is just a sample since I cannot provide the real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the input and output XMLs are similar, you can start with copying the input data as is using `identity transform`

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can match the `<parent>` node which do not have `<impvalue>` as its child since those are the nodes wherein the child `<impvalue>` needs to be added.

```
<xsl:template match="parent[not(impvalue)]">
```

Using a condition, you can check the `count` of `<children>` nodes having its own child nodes.

```
<xsl:when test="count(children/*) != 0">
```

The complete XSLT is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  match <parent> having no <impvalue> child -->
    <xsl:template match="parent[not(impvalue)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            <impvalue>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(children/*) != 0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </impvalue>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<info>
    <parent index="0">
        <name>test1</name>
        <children />
        <impvalue>false</impvalue>
    </parent>
    <parent index="1">
        <name>test2</name>
        <children>
            <VALUE index="0">test3</VALUE>
            <VALUE index="1">test4</VALUE>
        </children>
        <impvalue>true</impvalue>
    </parent>
    <parent index="2">
        <name>test3</name>
        <impvalue>true</impvalue>
    </parent>
    <parent index="3">
        <name>test4</name>
        <impvalue>false</impvalue>
    </parent>
</info>
```